# Different se'ifim of the Tur

Tags: shulchan-aruch, tur, simanim

I've noticed that there are two different se'if numbering systems in the Tur. In the Shiras Devorah, one is in bold, and the other is in script in parentheses:

[image: Tur]

It seems like one might refer to the Shulchan Aruch and one might refer to the Ein Mishpat, but I'm really not sure. Who developed these two numbering systems and what are they pointing to?

Comment: To help make sure we're all talking about the same thing, can you list a specific example of each and/or circle them in the image? A lot of the letters in the text are markers for comments by the various commentaries there.

Comment: I believe the parentheses points to the derisha. The bold seifim were done by Shiras Devora and correspond to the seifim in the Shulchan Aruch

Comment: @robev But then why would they be in the divrei hamaschil of the Bais Yosef as well?

Comment: I see what you mean. Newer versions of Shiras Devora don't seem to have what you show as I haven't seen this. To me it looks like they added every time the beis Yosef commented on a line of the tur, but it's hard to tell with your limited screenshot

Comment: @robev I just got this Tur a few months ago. Re: the Bais Yosef, there are divrei hamaschil without any numbering, which suggests that it's unrelated to the divrei hamaschil of - well - any of the peirushim. All of them have some divrei hamaschil without numbers.

Comment: The numbering in the BY also refers to the relevant seif in Shulchan Aruch, IINM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the old Tur there was only the text and the Bais Yosef around it. Shiras Devorah "invented" a numbering system as they assumed that the people using the Tur do so in advance of learning the Shulchan Aruch. As such the bold numbering system follows the Se'ifim in Shulchan Aruch. So if, for example, a certain section in the Tur is disucssed in Se'if Bais of the Shulchan Aruch, a bold Bais is shown. At times a seif in shulchan aruch comes from multiple places within the Tur and Bais Yosef, at which point the paranthesized numbers are used to show you which is the first, second.. part of the se'if. At times only the Bais Yosef discusses a future se'if of the Shulchan Aruch. For such instances the bold number is only in the Bais Yosef.

Comment: So after examining a bit more thoroughly, the parenthesis/Rashi script numbering system matches the sugyos mentioned in the beginning of the se'if (whether that is also an addition of the Shiras Devorah, I'm not sure). It seems that the Tur wrote the simanim in a structured way that can be split up by topic; the Beis Yosef deviated from that slightly in writing the Shulchan Aruch. But the parentheses/Rashi numbers can be reasonably considered the "se'ifim" of the Tur.